# Recursive function in a character array for finding a consonant in the first 3 elements in the array

Tags: c, function, recursion

To make it clearer , in the first three elements (characters) in the array to search and find the consonant and put it on the first element . Example we will take a char array A[] .
First three elements are A[i], A[i+1], A[i+2] , if the consonant is on A[i+1] It should move to A[i] 
That is A[i]=A[i+1] ... Hard time explaning it , but hope you guys catch my drift.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <ctype.h>


int changeup(char* a[],int k,int j, int x)

{

int i=0;


  if(*a[k]!='a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')

  a[x]=a[k];

  return changeup(a,k++,x++,j++);

  if(*a[j]!='a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')

  a[x]=a[j];

  return changeup(a,k++,x++,j++);

   if(*a[x]!='a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')

    return changeup(a,k++,x++,j++);

    else {

        return;
    }

   int main (void)

   {

    char * a[5];

    int i=0,j,k,x,n;

    char* p;


    n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

     k=i+2;

        j=i+1;

        x=i;


    *p=changeup(a,k,j,x);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){


    printf("%s",a[i]);

   }

    return 0;

   }






   }
```

Comment: You posted a fact, what's the question?

Comment: If you try something and post where you are having problems in your code, you might get some useful feedback.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarounMaroun How can i inspect only the first three elements , and then move by one place and inspect those three elements and so on..

Comment: @Lolapanza It is not clear from your post whether you need to traverse only three characters or each three characters of a string.

Comment: And why should the first three elements of `A[]` be `A[i]`, `A[i+1]`, `A[i+2]`?

Comment: I'm just giving an example, they dont have to be , but i want from those three elements to find a consonant and put it in the first element if there are no consonants the pointer moves by 1 in this case it will be on the second element . @WeatherVane

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Each three Vlad , i posted a code but have some trouble with it.

Comment: The first thing I spot from your code is that there are two `return` statements which are not enclosed in `{braces}` so as to be in the code block following the previous `if()` statement, i.e., the code will `return` unconditionally at the first occurrence.

Comment: @Lolapanza But a, e, i, o, u are not consonants.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that's why OP wrote `!=`, although the following `||` usage is incorrect. There is so much wrong with this code it is hard to know where to begin.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow There is a ! sign there , but i dont know if i can do that with arrays.

Comment: @WeatherVane Do you understand my problem ? Ispecting every three elements and putting the consonant in the first one and moving by one place , if there are none also moving by one place , im kind of beginner so i could use some help :)

Comment: `*a[k]` would be an element of a pointer array. `a[k]` is an element of a char array. Try `if(a[k]!='a' && a[k]!='e' && a[k]!='i' && a[k]!='o' && a[k]!='u') {/*consonant*/}`

Comment: Another thing is you will need to find a way of halting the recursion after the third char.

Comment: And lowercase the string first, or lowercase the vowel tests.

Comment: @Lolapanza Please shows an example of the execution result. E.g "abc" --> "bac" or "bbc", "abcdef" --> "bcdaef" etc..

Comment: "Tarantino" ="Tarnntnno" The first consonant of the three elements will be put on the first spot. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: You should not be calling `changeup()` three times within itself. You should be calling itself once, with a limit on the recursion.

Comment: @WeatherVane Any idea on how to do that? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to make use of this vowel testing function.

```
#include <ctype.h>

//return 1 if ch is a vowel
int vowel (int ch) {
    int chl = tolower(ch);
    return (chl=='a' || chl=='e' || chl=='i' || chl=='o' || chl=='u');
}

...

if (!vowel(a[k])) {    // if a consonant
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static inline bool vowel(char ch){
    char lch = tolower(ch);
    return lch == 'e' || lch == 'a' || lch == 'i' || lch == 'o' || lch == 'u';
}

static inline bool consonant(char ch){
    return isalpha(ch) && !vowel(ch);
}

void proc(char *s){
    bool moved = false;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        if(!s[i])
            return;
        if(!moved && consonant(s[i])){
            moved = true;
            s[0] = s[i];
        }
    }
    proc(s + 3);
}

int main(void){
    char str[] = "Tarantino";
    proc(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);//Tarnntnno
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thaks alot dude , you are awesome. Kinda complicated but ill find my way around it :D